# Getting error message java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called! while returning ResponseEntity<>

Tags: java

Im getting error while returning return new ResponseEntity<>(jsonObject, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST); in the below code where im printing the line:LOG.trace("Invalid Client provided"); in the else part

```
@Action("VALIDATE")
@RequestMapping(value = "/validate", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<JSONObject> valCode(HttpServletRequest request, String userId, String code,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, TokenIssuerException {

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    if (code != null) {

        ICode cacheCode = tokenCache.getCode(code, null);

        IClientInfo clientInfo = clientAuthCore.getClient(request, response, true);

        boolean checkClientId = checkClientID(clientInfo, cacheCode);
        if (checkClientId) {
```

//  business logic

```
        } else {
            LOG.trace("Invalid Client provided");
            return new ResponseEntity<>(jsonObject, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    } else {
        LOG.trace("Invalid parameters");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(jsonObject, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please check your implementation of clientAuthCore.getClient(request, response, true), suspecting it already did write/'responded' on the output stream

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm returning null instead of another JSON object which is resolution since already getwrite is called.